How should we describe the size of a piece?
In order to help with descriptions of pieces especially, should we define a standard for descriptive nomenclature?
eg Length x Width x Height of the basic shape followed by additional identifiers
this could give us examples such as a block 8 x 2 x 1, a 16 x 1 x 1 with 15 holes (technics), or a plate 8 x 2 x 1/3

Generally, elements are described by the number of studs, and then height is defined by them being a plate or brick.
It's then mostly the "specials" or over/under sized bricks that are given a height:



If you actually know the part, the best strategy is to use the exact same name as another site, possibly linking to it or even inserting a picture when practical.
No need to reinvent our own naming conventions when there are already so many in use. I prefer to align on LDraw names which can be found via Peeron.
